# Can't open text file on VSC with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hello I'm starting with python and VSC so I wrote this code on an internet course assignment that works fine on my command prompt but when I run it on VSC it won't work:

```
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
count = dict()
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("From "):
        email = line.split()[1]
        count[email] = count.get(email,0)+1

bigemail = None
emailcnt = None
for key,value in count.items():
    if bigemail is None or value > emailcnt:
        bigemail = key
        emailcnt = value

print(bigemail,emailcnt)
```

The file is in the same folder as my code and the error from the compiler is:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mbox-short.txt'
  File "C:\Users\....\Documents\Python\...\PFE\Data Struct\HW_9.4.py", line 1, in <module>
    fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
```

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Add full path to the file in the open statement. When you run it from VS, the working directory is not the same as where the script is located.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? As an aside, you should use a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `.vscode/launch.json` file with the content

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to change the current working directory to the directory of the current file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting the name of the file, use the exact location.

for example: `C://user/desktop/folder/mbox-short.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the information Oscar!! I'll use the absolute path on other new projects :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running your code from another place and your folder is at a different place. You just need to `python W_9.4.py` in the same directory where your code and text file present it. It will work then.

if you don't want to go to directly then you will have to provide the full path of your text file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! The file is actually on the same folder but apparently my .vscode/launch.json was missing the cwd line in this case: ```"cwd": ${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick options:

1 - Copy `mbox-short.txt` to same location of the python script at `C:\Users\....\Documents\Python\...\PFE\Data Struct\` to be able to use the **relative path** as you've now

2 - Provide the **absolute path** to the current location of `mbox-short.txt`

```
fh = open("C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\mbox-short.txt")
# fh = open("C:/absolute/path/to/mbox-short.txt") # also works
```

---

Reading:

- [Difference Between Absolute and Relative Path](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-absolute-and-relative-path/)

Comment: Thank you for the information and the reading link it's really interesting since I'm new at high level programming I appreciate all information to understand in a deeper way. :D  even though my actual problem was a not completely defined .vscode/launch.json I'll use more often the absolute path for other files :)