# VSC python won't open .txt files in the same directory (relative path only works for the top level of the workspace folder)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'movies.txt' for this line:

`with open("movies.txt", "r", encoding= "utf-8") as movies:`

So far (from what I've tried) I'm figuring it's a VSC workspace/file nesting depth issue...maybe some settings I don't know exist somewhere.

Is there a way to fix this? Should I stop using nested files? How many levels of nested files are okay? (I'm 3 levels down from my main workspace folder) New to coding and VSC (using desktop version) so not sure what's good practice for organising files.

Some stuff I've checked/tried:

- The files are definitely in the same directory.
- Renaming the file
- Moving everything to a different directory
- Testing with completely independent code and .txt file, both in the same directory (same result)
- The full file path works fine (but I need the relative path as I need to upload the code and .txt file later)
- Restarted VSC
- Restarted PC
- Updated the launch.json file as per:
  [Can't open text file on VSC with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434507/cant-open-text-file-on-vsc-with-python)
- Asked chatGPt 3.5
- Disabled recent extensions
- Opening the .txt file from the command line with python (opens and reads fine)
- Moving the python file and the .txt file to the top level of the workspace folder (works fine)
- Removing and resetting my workspace folder.
- Adding the folder immediately containing the files to the workspace directly.

Comment: What is the current working directory of your terminal? Whenever you run the program it runs it in the current working directory..

Comment: It sounds like the current working directory is simply different from the file's location.  It's generally more reliable to use complete absolute paths instead of relying on the working directory.  (e.g. Using a per-environment config to define an absolute "root path" for data files and letting the code work with relative paths from that known starting point.)

Comment: If you run using Ctrl F5 shortcut, or the play button, then yeah it runs the program from the top of the workspace.. instead, `cd` to the directory of your Python file on your vscode terminal (or open up a separate terminal in that directory, then try doing `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py` depending on your installation

Comment: On the other hand: You can try out `pathlib` library from the standard python library. Makes it very easy if you wanna work with paths. And check out the `__file__` special variable in a Python file, gives the absolute path of that particular file. You can thus get the path of the executing file on the fly and still make your code work.

Comment: Show your working directory and the way you execute code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Check your current working directory or
you can specify full path to the file like below :

```
with open("/full/path/to/your/movies.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as movies:
    # code
```

Comment: Thanks @a_n , David and everyone I had confused the workspace and current working directory and helpful to know how to set up paths properly.